# How do I add classes to form elements in the theme layer?

Tags: theming, forms

I want to do it in template.php. The form ID is page_node_form, and there are six form text fields. The default class is "form-text."

I want to add "text1," "text2," etc after "form-text" to each input text class. How can I do it?

This is the HTML:

```
<input gtbfieldid="10" id="edit-field-14sq-und-0-value" name="field_14sq[und][0][value]" value="" size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text"> 
<input gtbfieldid="10" id="edit-field-14sq-und-0-value" name="field_15sq[und][0][value]" value="" size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text"> ....
```

Comment: If the form is in a block you could just use the skinr module to add a class: http://drupal.org/project/skinr

Answer (score 6):

This is an ideal situation for a preprocess function.

I don't have Drupal 7 working to test at the moment, but something like this in your template.php should do the trick.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_textfield(&$vars) {
  static $counter = 0;
  $counter++;
  $vars['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'test' . $counter;
}
```

Comment: if i want to use Override the theme function. how do i do?

Comment: you could ask that in a separate question, generally it is just mytheme_textfield() in your template.php file.

Comment: mytheme_preprocess_textfield  will overwrite all of the textfield in my theme? am i right?

Comment: It will allow you to modify every text field in the theme. You can put conditions in it to select only certain fields to change.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do it in your module, in your hook_form_alter for the node form add :

```
$form['field_14sq'][und][0][value]['#attributes'] ['class'][] = text1;
```