# add class to form element

Tags: 7, forms

```
function ajax_register_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   $form['fbuser'] = array(
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#markup' => 'You have a facebook account?',
      '#weight' => -10,
    );
   $form['login_link'] = array(
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#markup' => '<a class="facebook-action-connect" rel="nofollow" href="foo"><img src="foo" alt=""></a></div>',
      '#weight' => -6,      
    );
   }
```

How can I add a class to this div's?

Comment: Have a look at the answer to [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3817/how-do-i-add-classes-to-form-elements-in-the-theme-layer?rq=1). You might need to preprocess `theme_form_element` instead (totally depends what you need to do), but that's the basic idea

Answer (score 15):

You might be looking for the `#attributes` property that you can add to forms and form elements. See example below

```
function ajax_register_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   $form['fbuser'] = array(
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#markup' => 'You have a facebook account?',
      '#weight' => -10,
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('my-class-1')),
    );
   $form['login_link'] = array(
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#markup' => '<a class="facebook-action-connect" rel="nofollow" href="foo"><img src="foo" alt=""></a></div>',
      '#weight' => -6,
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('my-class-2')),
    );
   }
```

Comment: it seems right, but it doesn't work. maybe it's ajax login/register module cache or some settings. i don't know

Comment: You should add an element to the class array, instead of overwriting it. Example : $form['name']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-control';

Comment: #attributes is not working with item type, see documentation! (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#item)

Answer (score 6):

According to the drupal official form api guide, the item type cannot use the `#attributes` property:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#item

A workaround could be using the `#prefix` and `#suffix` properties:

```
$form['fbuser'] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#markup' => 'You have a facebook account?',
  '#weight' => -10,
  '#prefix' => '<span class="my_class">',
  '#suffix' => '</span>', // close the span openend by the #prefix property
);
```

The drawback is that the css class will be added to a parent of the item element, not to the item itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `'#attributes' => array('class' => array('my-class'))` or else you can do this:

```
$form['html_markup_address'] = array(
  '#markup' => l(t('Add New Address'), 'mymodule/nojs',
   array('attributes' => array('class' => array('ctools-use-modal'))))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `_form_set_class()`

Docs: https://api.drupal.org/api/function/_form_set_class/7.x

Example:

```
_form_set_class($element, array('my-class'));
```